# Adding UIView to a tableviewcell's contentView

Tags: uiview, uitableview, subview, addsubview

I am adding a UIView as a subview of each tableviewcell's contentView and I am getting some major problems.

I attached a screen shot of what it is doing.
http://i44.tinypic.com/11kw0ms.jpg
Those black bars at the bottom of each cell are not supposed to be there.

Heres my code:

Header

```
@class CalendarCell;
@interface ...{
    CalendarCell *calCell;
}
```

Implementation

```
#import "CalendarCell.h"

...In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    calCell = [[CalendarCell alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalendarCell" bundle:nil];
    [calCell.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:calCell.view];
    [calCell release];
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height of your cell.